# NPE is thrown at static class declaration

Tags: java, static, nullpointerexception

I'm facing a weird NPE in some static class declaration and I don't know why.

I have a dummy object just to carry data (is a inner class), as follows:

```
private static class MyStaticClass { //this is line 400
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;

    private Boolean flag1 = Boolean.FALSE;
    private Boolean flag2 = Boolean.TRUE;
    private Boolean flag3 = Boolean.TRUE;
    private List<String> list = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

    public MyStaticClass() {}

    public MyStaticClass(AnotherDataObject data) {
        a = data.getA();
        b = data.getB();
        c = data.getC();
        d = data.getD();
    }

}
```

The client code (MyClass.myMethod) looks like:

```
public class MyClass {

    public void myMethod() {
        Map<Key, MyStaticClass> thisMap = new HashMap<Key, MyStaticClass>(DEFAULT_BUFFSIZE);

        //stuff

        for() {
            //stuff
            MyStaticClass instance = new MyStaticClass(value1, value2, value3);
            thisMap.put(generatedKey, instance);
        }

        //stuff

        for() { //every key
            MyStaticClass myStaticClassInstance = map.get(key); //this isn't null, i checked it.
            if(randomObject.flag && myStaticClassInstance.flag2) {
                //do stuff
            }
        }

        //more stuff
    }

    private static class MyStaticClass {
        //look the previous code snippet for more info
    }
}
```

Now, I have a function that runs linear (no concurrency) and at some point evaluates the next sentence:

```
if(randomObject.flag && myStaticClassInstance.flag2) //randomObject is another class
```

When the JVM evaluates this sentence, an NPE is thrown at MyStaticClass declaration (private static class ...) and I don't know why.

There is no static blocks, the flag2 is never set to null.

Let's say that the "static class MyStaticClass" is declared at line 400. So, the stacktrace is like that:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mypackage.MyClass$MyStaticClass.access$1300(MyClass.java:400)
    at org.mypackage.MyClass.myMethod(MyClass.java:283)
    at org.mypackage.AsyncDestination$1.run(AsyncDestination.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

EDIT: I've added a simple test using a MyStaticClass as null (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/35b94fea2a993fc350e4), the exception is similar, but it is thrown at the property declaration line, not the line where the class is declarated.

Comment: why don't you make the fields static?

Comment: There is nothing special about a class being `private static` You get an NPE just because you dereferenced a `null` just like anywhere else in your code.  I suggest you break point this code and check it out in your debugger.

Comment: @ScaryWombat because it is not actually static. Just an inner class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey myStaticClassInstance is an object. Let's say that I declare the static class at line 400. The stacktrace is saying that an NPE is throwing at line 400 MyClass$MyStaticClass.access$1300. What is that .access property?

Comment: Any special reason for `private static` and if you have `private` class from where you want to access it?

Comment: added the stacktrace and line references

Comment: What is that strange `org.mypackage.AsyncDestination`?

Comment: An event handler, it is just a Callable consuming tasks (events) from a unbounded queue.

Comment: The `.access$...` methods are [synthetic methods](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073578/java-s-synthetic-methods.html) generated by the compiler to allow access to private fields in inner classes. Please provide the code around `org.mypackage.MyClass.myMethod(MyClass.java:283)`. That should explain the access trick being used and should therefore offer a rrason for the NPE. If it is `if(randomObject.flag && myStaticClassInstance.flag2)` please post code that details how `myStaticClassInstance` is created as it is likely that that is `null`.

Comment: I've added that information. I pushed to live this night the change using just boolean primitives. The error is gone by now, but I don't understand why, since any property was never null :S

Answer (score 1):

When declaring fields which could be primitives, you should ask yourself the question; should this be `null` or not.  If the value can be null you can use a wrapper or poison pill value.  However is a field shouldn't be `null` you should not use a wrapper if you can avoid it.  Using a primitive will not only be faster, but it is also clearer the value cannot be `null`

In answer to your question, you are getting an NPE because you have a value which is `null`  Using a `private static class` doesn't change this.  I suggest you breakpoint your code and look at it in your debugger.

> The stacktrace is saying that an NPE is throwing at line 400 MyClass$MyStaticClass.access$1300. What is that .access property?

Using private fields and classes can be confusing as the JVM doesn't actually support access to private members in the way Java does.  The compiler generates code to allow this access, resulting in accessor methods.

From the exception, the most likely explanation is that flag2 is `null`.

So I suggest

- use your debugger to see what is going on.
- use primitives were possible
- make your access package local instead of private if the members are accessed in other classes.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Anyway I think i'm facing some weird context problem or JVM bug. 

Launching the event from a Quartz task or launching it from a web thread (the event is handled by the same event handler thread), got different results. The event created from Quartz, fails with this exception. The event created from web thread, runs successfully.

Comment: @SamuelGarcía The only way to get a better understanding of the problem is to debug it.  You could add logging/printing just before and just after this line to see the values as well.

Comment: As soon as you say "JVM bug", you actually mean "Something I don't understand". When investigating a problem, do-not-go-there. You must with all the willingness you can muster want this to be something you do wrong yourself so you can fix it.

Comment: You're right, that's why I said "some weird context problem" first :) I assume I'm doing something wrong when the event is fired from the Quartz job, even when the event is processed by the same thread and the same worker, despite its origin.

Comment: I've switched to primitives in live env. and it worked so far. I don't know why, though.

Comment: @SamuelGarcía most likely you are failing to initialise the variable correctly.  With a primitive this is a `false` value which doesn't appear to cause a problem, but with a Boolean it is `null` which can trigger an exception.